# How to increase Session timeout to more than 12 hours?

Tags: api

Currently the Session setting is having the maximum time out value as 12 hrs.

Is there any way to remove this session time out constraint? Can we make this feature disable by raising a ticket with salesforce .

Comment: I'm curious what the reason would be for wanting to have a session timeout longer than 12 hours? Why not just log in again if you need access after 12 hours idle?

Comment: Thanks Doug for the reply. Actually my understanding was wrong.Session timeout only comes into the picture when user is idle  ,but if user is active for more than 12 hrs then session time out will never come into the picture. Please confirm if this is the correct understanding.

Comment: Yes, the session timeout is the period of inactivity required before the session becomes invalid. For example if your session timeout is 1 hour you can use SF all day long without needing to log in again, provided you don't leave it idle for over 1 hour during that time.

Comment: Thanks alot Doug.I have posted one other question . Could you please let me know your thought on that."http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44415/iframe-with-different-domain"

Answer (score 1):

No, but if you use a client app, you can make the login perpetual with OAuth, or you can use SSO to avoid having to log in at all while on the network. As a note, as long as your session is being used, the session won't time out. Twelve hours should be enough for all normal use cases.

Comment: Thanks sfdcFox for the reply. Could you please take a look at other question "http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44415/iframe-with-different-domain%22" of mine and let me know your useful thought